# I have 6 popovers that open at the same time but want them to open one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that creates a div with 6 experiences and each experience has a popover. But when I click the experience to open its popover I get all 6 popovers open. How do I give a unique id to each popover.

This is my experience component

```
    import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import gastronomia from 'assets/experiences/gastronomia.jpg';
import productos from 'assets/experiences/productos.jpg';
import giftcard from 'assets/experiences/giftcard.jpg';
import diversion from 'assets/experiences/diversion.jpg';
import deporte from 'assets/experiences/deporte.jpg';
import belleza from 'assets/experiences/belleza.jpg';
import gastronomiaExperiences from 'data/gastronomia';
import productosExperiences from 'data/productos';
import giftcardExperiences from 'data/giftcard';
import diversionExperiences from 'data/diversion';
import deporteExperiences from 'data/deporte';
import bellezaExperiences from 'data/belleza';


// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Custom root className. */
  className: PropTypes.string,

};

// Default props definitions.
const defaultProps = {
  className: null,
};

// Component's styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });



/**
 * Component used to render a grid of experiences.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);


const handleClick = event => {
setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
};

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

    const experience = (img, title, category, id, popoverCategory) => (
      <div className="experience" aria-describedby={id} id={id} onClick={handleClick} >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>

        <Popper id={id} open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id} >
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={popoverCategory}
          alt="Puntospoint"
        />
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );


    return (
      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', 'gastronomia', open, anchorEl, gastronomiaExperiences)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard','giftcard', open, anchorEl, giftcardExperiences)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', 'deporte', open, anchorEl, deporteExperiences)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', 'productos', open, anchorEl, productosExperiences)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', 'diversion', open, anchorEl, diversionExperiences)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', 'belleza', open, anchorEl, bellezaExperiences)}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Experiences.propTypes = propTypes;

// Component default props.
Experiences.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Experiences;
```

I am new to react and material ui so I am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each experience its own id and remove the anchorEl parameter by changing this:

```
      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', id, open, anchorEl, gastronomiaExperiences)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard', id, open, anchorEl, giftcardExperiences)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', id, open, anchorEl, deporteExperiences)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', id, open, anchorEl, productosExperiences)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', id, open, anchorEl, diversionExperiences)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', id, open, anchorEl, bellezaExperiences)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

to this

```
      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', 'gastronomia', open, gastronomiaExperiences)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard','giftcard', open, giftcardExperiences)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', 'deporte', open, deporteExperiences)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', 'productos', open, productosExperiences)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', 'diversion', open, diversionExperiences)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', 'belleza', open, bellezaExperiences)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

That will give each experience own id. Then all you have to do is check whether the id of the `anchorEl` is the same as id you gave the experience.

Change this:

```
<Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>

            <LogoSlider logos={popoverCategory} />
          </div>
</Popper>
```

to this

```
<Popper id={id} open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>

            <LogoSlider logos={popoverCategory} />
          </div>
        </Popper>
```

also remove the useCallback hook, you don't need that.

Change this:

```
    const experience = useCallback((img, title, category, id, open, anchorEl, popoverCategory) => (
```

to this:

```
    const experience =(img, title, category, id, popoverCategory) => (
```

Comment: I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null refering to this line <Popper id={id} open={anchorEl.id === id} anchorEl={anchorEl}>

Comment: No you don't need to do that

Comment: ./src/components/Experiences.jsx
Syntax error: Unexpected token (133:7)

  131 |    </div>
  132 |    
> 133 |  ), []); I get this error becouse I do not have the callback any more.. should I delete the ,[]) or do I add useCallback

Comment: Yes, my bad. remove the whole `, []);` from that line.

Comment: shoulding the ; be at the end?

Comment: It doesn't have to, but you can leave it there.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null and in the console it says id is defined but never used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205751/discussion-between-ot413-and-nanodine).

Answer (score 0):

make 5 promises and reduce them into one big promise and use this promise Like this

```
const promisesArray = [Prmise1,Prmise2,Prmise3,Prmise4,Prmise5];
const allInOnePromise = promisesArray.reduce( (previousPromise, nextPromise) => {
  return previousPromise.then(() => {
    return nextPromise;
  });
}, Promise.resolve());

allInOnePromise.then(_=>{});
```